# How do I find out which properties had validation errors in a Blazor EditContext?

Tags: blazor

I have an `EditForm`, and am having some problems in that something is causing a validation error, but not something bound to a control on the form.

To clarify, I have a model for the form (some properties removed for clarity)...

```cs
public class RenewalViewModel {
    public int CurrentTermId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CompanyOverview> AvailableCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

`CurrentTermId` is not shown on the form, but is needed to identity the term when the form is submitted. `Start`, `End` and some omitted properties are displayed on the form, can be edited by the user, ad are what is used when saving the data.

Along with those, there are a few properties, such as `AvailableCompanies` that hold data needed for validation, but are not used when the form is submitted. I need them on the model so the validator can see them (I'm using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)).

I suspect, but am not sure, that somehow, one of these associated properties (eg a `CompanyOverview` or something associated with that) has been changed, and is in an invalid state. However, I don't know how to find out what property of which object is causing the validation error in order to work out why it's happening.

In order to try and work out what was happening, I changed the form's submit handler to look like this...

```cs
    private void OnSubmitRenew(EditContext ec) {
      if (ec.ValidateObjectTree()) {
        // Save the data
      } else {
        Debug.WriteLine("Invalid data: " + string.Join(". ", ec.GetValidationMessages()));
      }
    }
```

The problem is that this only shows the validation errors, not which properties caused them.

Is there a way of working out which properties caused the errors? I had a look in the `EditContext`, but can't see anything useful in there.

Thanks

Comment: Hi there... " but not something bound to a control on the form", if so, why look for errors with the EditContext. You should provide much more context. There is no way we solve this issue without revealing your code.

Comment: @enet I'm not deliberately looking for those errors, and I don't even know if that's the problem. The model has some associated data this is needed for the validation, and I suspect that some of that data might have a validation problem. However whichever it is, I want to know if I can find out which property is causing the error. Does that make it any clearer? שמחת פורים ושבת שלום

Comment: @enet I've updated the question to make it (hopefully) clearer what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in that something is causing a validation error

How do you know ? Were you notified about it ? If so, what is the notification message ?

Validation error are usually in the form: First name is required... BirthofDate is required...etc. So most often we know what has gone wrong.

I'd suggest you try this code to locate the source of the error:

```
@code
    {
        private EditContext EditContext;
        private RenewalViewModel Model = new RenewalViewModel();
     
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

            base.OnInitialized();
        }

          // Note: The OnFieldChanged event is raised for each field in the model
        private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, 
                                                FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            

           // Each time a field changes this code is executed. 
              EditContext.Validate() returns true if
            // validation succeeded; that is, all fields pass validation
            if (EditContext.Validate())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validation succeeded");
            }
            else
            {
                // This is the culprit
                Console.WriteLine(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName);
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I know something went wrong as validation message were raised, but as I only ever show these right next to the field in question, my messages are "Required" or "Wrong format" or whatever, so no way of seeing from there which field raised the error. I eventually tracked down which it was by expanding them temporarily, which led me to find out what was going wrong (although I don't understand why, but will be posting a separate question about that).

Comment: As for your code, couple of questions. 1) How does Blazor know to connect the form's `EditContext` to the one you create manually in the `OnInitialized` method? 2) Is the second code line a mistake, or is `Comment` a built-in Blazor class I've not seen yet? Thanks again.

Comment: I provided partial code concentrating on the main issue in question... For question 1: It sees this: <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext"> For question 2: Comment is the model class. This should be clear from the instantiation of the EditContext in the OnInitialized method... I guess you didn't try this code as you seem to have been confused about the code. I hope that now it is clear, and you can employ it to find out the culprit

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You didn't show that you had set the form's `EditContext` to the one you instantiated, and as I've never done that (always relied on the model to sort that out), it didn't occur to me that this was what you'd done. As for 2), the reason I asked was because you had `RenewalViewModel Model = new Comment()`, which looked like a typo, mixing up my `RenewalViewModel` model class with a `Comment` model class. Thanks again.